# Map view not focus on annotation

Tags: ios, view, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Hello i am new to ios and showing an annoatation on map view using lat and long coming from server. 
    I have one view controller in which i am adding map and showing position of lat and long. But  my problem is whenever i am adding annotation map is not focusing on annotattion insted of it everytime i want pinch map view then map is going to at annoatation i dont know why this is happening?

```
zoomLocation.latitude = latmpa.doubleValue;
zoomLocation.longitude = logmpa.doubleValue;
annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = zoomLocation;
annotationPoint.title = @"masjid....";
[mapView selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:YES];

[mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

here is my code adding in viewwillappera
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to center the map by use the following code.

```
mapView.centerCoordinate = annotationPoint.coordinate;
```

Comment: thnaks it working correctly. but i have one more question ex if i give lat and long aberdeen, UK it pointing to london and needs to zoom out two times then aberdeen is shown...can you help me in this

Comment: @user2902101  I have the answer but it will be illegal to post the answer here as the answer will be different from the above said question. You can post another question on stack and ask me through this comment post and also post the question link here.

Comment: Hi, how to do this with animations ?

Comment: try this [mapView selectAnnotation:annotationPoint animated:YES];

Answer (score 2):

Milan's solution does what you need without animation.
If you want to do this with animation, you should use:

```
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:location animated:YES];
```